# Compare Map Value with list using Stream API

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, java-stream

Need to collect  the common value from a List of String and from a MAP having String as KEY and List as VALUE.

Snippet:

```
public Map<String, List> maping() throws Exception {

String id="test";

List<String> no = new ArrayList<String>();

no.add("123456");
no.add("654321");
no.add("11223344");

Map<String, List> info = new HashMap<String, List>();
info .put(id, no);

return info ;
}
```

---

```
    public List getInfo() {
    
    List<String> listNo = new ArrayList<String>();
    listNo.add("123456");
    listNo.add("654321");
    listNo.add("135790");
    listNo.add("123987");
    listNo.add("11223344");
    return listNo;
    
}
```

In third method need to compare the List and MAP value and collect the common no in a List.
Please guide using JAVA 8 Stream API

Comment: It's not entirely clear what exactly you want to achieve. With a given id, you could do `map.get(id)` to get the list associated to the id, and then compare all values of this list if they are present in the list provided by `getInfo()`. Then your question has little to do with a Map at all, and merely boils down to "how to get the *intersection* between two lists?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
public List<String> collectCommonNumbers(Map<String, List<String>> inputMap, List<String> inputList) {
  return inputMap.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).distinct().filter(inputList::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```